Why is this simple tkinter ui not displaying the specified label?
I created a simple window with tkinter, with a title and a label. The title seems to be working, but the label won't show up no matter what I do. I tried it with and without specifying a font. I'm using Python 3.12.3 and I'm on MacOS Ventura 13.3.
Here's the code and the resulting (blank) UI below it:
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry("300x300")
root.title("Pass Stat")

label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello World!")
label.pack(padx=12, pady=12)

root.mainloop()

Resulting window
I tried this code as written above, with tkinter's default text font on the label, and with no font specification at all.

The Tkinter window isn't supposed to have a black background, by default.  I suspect that your Label is actually there, it's just being displayed as black-on-black.  This has been an ongoing problem with Tkinter on MacOS, but I've never seen a description of the exact situation that causes it, nor any fix.

it works nicely on windows...

the following snippet may be of use in determining the underlying issue - dumps the (known) properties of tk being used.
Not at a mac to test this, will post an update after testing on mac if anything substantial differs.
The below was tested usingpython 3.8.10 on linux mint 20.x
cat jchurch828.py 
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
vinfo="TkVersion : " + str(tk.TkVersion)

config_options = root.config()

print(vinfo + "\nConfig properties found are:\n" )

for ki in config_options.keys():
    value = root.cget(ki)
    print("Property: " + str(ki) + " Value: " + str(root.cget(ki)) )

dummy = tk.Label(root)  # see what the defaults are - we'll delete once finished

print( "\ndefault label properties" +
        "\nbackground color is :" + str(dummy.cget("bg")) +
        "\nforeground is : " + str( dummy.cget("fg")) +
        "\nfont is : " + str( dummy.cget("font")) )

dummy.destroy();

exit()

python3 jchurch828.py 
TkVersion : 8.6
Config properties found are:

Property: bd Value: 0
Property: borderwidth Value: 0
Property: class Value: Tk
Property: menu Value: 
Property: relief Value: flat
Property: screen Value: 
Property: use Value: 
Property: background Value: #d9d9d9
Property: bg Value: #d9d9d9
Property: colormap Value: 
Property: container Value: 0
Property: cursor Value: 
Property: height Value: 0
Property: highlightbackground Value: #d9d9d9
Property: highlightcolor Value: #000000
Property: highlightthickness Value: 0
Property: padx Value: 0
Property: pady Value: 0
Property: takefocus Value: 0
Property: visual Value: 
Property: width Value: 0

default label properties
background color is :#d9d9d9
foreground is : #000000
font is : TkDefaultFont

hope this is of use.
UPDATE: tested on macos Darwin, differences below. Window displayed as per others without issue.
mac.info                              | mint.info
Property: background Value: systemWindowBackgroundColor       | Property: background Value: #d9d9d9
Property: bg Value: systemWindowBackgroundColor           | Property: bg Value: #d9d9d9
Property: highlightbackground Value: systemWindowBackgroundCo | Property: highlightbackground Value: #d9d9d9
Property: highlightcolor Value: systemTextColor           | Property: highlightcolor Value: #000000
background color is :systemWindowBackgroundColor          | background color is :#d9d9d9
foreground is : systemTextColor                   | foreground is : #000000


You can change the background to a different colour like Yellow.
Here i change the background of both:

the main window (root)
Label (bg='yellow')

so the code looks like this:
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry("300x300")
root.title("Pass Stat")

root.configure(bg='yellow')

label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello World!", bg='yellow')
label.pack(padx=12, pady=12)

root.mainloop()

and the screen (on windows) looks like this:

I expect the Mac would look similar to this.
